# Find which (not referenced) DLL contains a definition

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a large directory of .Net DLLs and I want to search them for the one that provides a given definition.  For example, I want to find the DLL that provides the "MyCoolClass" so that I can include it as a reference.

I could load each dll and see if it compiles, but there are over 500 DLLs in the folder and I don't want to check them one by one.  What is an easy way to find the one I need to reference in my project?

Comment: Write a little console app that goes through the list, loads the dll, retrieves the classes, and looks for a type that matches your MyCoolClass's type.

Comment: Using a bit of reflection

Comment: It is perfectly valid for multiple assemblies to define a type with the same name (including namespace).

Answer (score -1):

One crude way I can think of is to find string MyCoolClass in those 500 files. Something like `findstr MyCoolClass file1.dll` wrapped in some sort of loop to identify which files contain this string. This will reduce count of candidate dll files.